# How to upload a python project on pythonanywhere

Tags: visual-studio, flask, pythonanywhere

I am new to Flask/Pythonanywhere. Thanks to Visual Studio, I have generated a template which works fine as a local host. I want to upload this template on pythonanywhere. I followed the tutorial, created a web app and deleted the default flask_app.py. I then upload my python project, reload my website and try to open the website which doesn't work (Error when opening website: "Something went wrong").

Am I not supposed to upload a project in python anywhere? If I have to upload python files as opposed to the entire project, what should I upload. Currently have txt/css/js files besides py files in my project, should I ignore them?

Thank you

Comment: Do you made of this instruction? https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Flask/

Comment: Yes I'm trying to use the first option: "The first option works well if you're just playing around and want to throw something together from scratch. Go to the Web Tab and hit Add a new Web App, and choose Flask and the Python version you want."

Comment: Check the error log to see what kind of error it throws at the bottom (most recent one); also make sure you uploaded ALL files that your project is using and correctly updated the WSGI file.